# What is the difference in this re expressions?

Tags: python, regex

i am testing the re expressions and the book example was:

```
if re.search('^X\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
```

But with my expression I reach the same result:

```
if re.search('^X\S*: [0-9]', line):
```

What's is the difference?, what do I not see?. Thank you.

Comment: The obvious difference is a dot and a plus, but what the difference in result us depends on the input which you did not give in your question.

Comment: You are right, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is two completely different regex expressions:

```
^X\S*: [0-9.]+
^X\S*: [0-9]
```

Comparing side-by-side yields the difference: `[0-9.]+` vs `[0-9]`.

The second one will only match *one* digit.

While the first one will match one number of digits and dots.

So, the second one will fail for the following examples:

```
X: 1.23
X: 123.3213.23131
```

And any other combination of digits + dot.

The same result will be only for something like this:

```
X: 1
```

Comment: It won't actually fail. It'll match the `X: 1` and stop, returning a match object. It would only fail if they asserted end of line `$` after the digits.

Comment: I mean it will fail to match the same text. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to match any line that begins with X: and a number, these are functionally equivalent within the context of your program. They will both find and match lines like these, and return TRUE for your IF statement:

```
X: 100
X: 9.23
X: 9912.2434.2424.2435
Xabc: 1
X-rf: 0.7
```

However, the patterns are not the same and if you use them in a different context, they may no longer be functionally equivalent. For example, if you need to match the entire line, you would have to use `re.search('^X\S*: [0-9.]+', line)`. The other pattern, `re.search('^X\S*: [0-9]', line)`, only will match a single digit 0-9 and nothing else after that.

Comment: Thank you, mate!. Now I understand it